# Get Microsoft Entra ID data using MSFlow

Tags: power-automate, dataverse

We have a Microsoft Entra ID table in Dynamics Dataverse. I'm trying to retrieve the Microsoft Entra ID table using MS Flow, but it throws an error. Does anyone have an idea? Please help. Error: Access Token not Found: Please make sure the plugin is registered and not called with app credentials.

Comment: Sorry but show us something and show us what you’ve done thus far and be specific.